# Installing a new, custom theme has "broke" current Wordpress installation

Tags: wordpress

I've just finished creating a new custom theme based on the [underscores](http://underscores.me/) framework, and It's ended up breaking my current wordpress installation after applying it.

Although everything is running fine on the front end, the back end is running really weird.

The following issues have presented themselves:

1. Trying to add a new post (either regular, or one of the new custom post types I've defined) just results in a blank page. Although the post has been created, the admin section gets stuck on the **wp-admin/post.php** page.
2. My media library no longer shows up in the media browser. Although all 6,000+ images are still there, none show up.
3. When logged in, it takes ages for the page to load in the Wordpress admin bar, as it appears it can no longer display the site stats (it just shows the broken image icon after it's finally finished loading in, when the new theme is selected).

I've tried to refresh the permalinks, but this hasn't worked.

Any ideas? I was hoping to re-launch my website today, but it looks like I might have to put it on hold...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get ahold of the devs for your framework.  Your experience is not an uncommon one.  It has happened to my sites several times.   Unless you want to tweak the php yourself, they will have to help you.

Comment: Oh no, I've just finished creating the theme myself, so I'm familiar with PHP and the way Wordpress works. Do you know the solution? Thanks for replying!

Comment: I don't have enough info to know exactly what the trouble is.  Troubleshooting Wordpress can be challenging at times.
A couple of things to try:

-Temporarily turn on displaying errors by putting `display_errors = on` in your php.ini file.  That might show some useful info to point up problems in the code

-Do you have a backup copy from yesterday?  Some hosting providers do daily backups so you can restore files back to a calendar day.  This has saved my behind more than once.  If you can restore it, perhaps you can roll the new theme out more slowly and see where errors crop up.

-

Answer (score 0):

Managed to sort this out. Turns out a function I had written to add a custom field to menu items broke the entire back end. Thanks for the help everyone!